# How do I update a column value and set a TTL for the whole row?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

i'm trying to update a column value (not key column) and to set new TTL for the whole row.
But when i execute the generated statement, only column ttl was updates and the other columns remain with the original, producing NULL values in future reads.

My app was written in Java and using datastax for querying, and the function for generating the statement is something like this.

```java
private Statement updateLastActivityStatement(int ttl, Long ts){
    return QueryBuilder.update(KEY_SPACE, TABLE_NAME)
        .with(QueryBuilder.set(LAST_ACTIVITY, ts))
        .where(QueryBuilder.eq(ENTRY_ID, userA))
        .and(QueryBuilder.eq(ID, userB))
        .using(QueryBuilder.ttl(ttl));
}
```

Comment: what cass version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTL is bound to a specific cell, so when you're updating only specific columns, then only them are updated. To update everything, you need to update all values

Answer (score 1):

The TTL only applies to the columns in the statement, not to all the columns in the row nor all the rows in the partition.

The only workaround I could think of is to set a default TTL on the table using the `default_time_to_live` option. Cheers!